# Want to prove an inequality of two norms in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces

So here is my problem,

Let $D:=[-d,d]\times[-d,d]$ and $C_0^{\infty}$(D) be the set of all smooth functions with compact support in $D$ which are zero on the boundary of $D$.

Moreover we have the two following inner products.

$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_0:L^2(D)\times L^2(D)\rightarrow\mathbb R$$
$$(f,g)\mapsto\int_Dfgdx$$
and
$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1:C^{\infty}_0(D)\times C^{\infty}_0(D)\rightarrow\mathbb R$$
$$(f,g)\mapsto\int_D\partial _{x_1}f\partial _{x_1}g+\partial _{x_2}f\partial _{x_2}gdx$$

Now I want to show the following inequality,

$$||f||_0\leq2d||f||_1$$
for all $f\in C^{\infty}_0(D)$.

This was my attempt,

For some $f\in C^{\infty}_0(D)$ we have,

$$4d^2||f||_1^2=||1||_0^2||f||_1^2=||1||_0^2(||\partial_{x_1}f||_0^2+||\partial_{x_2}f||_0^2)=||1||_0^2||\partial_{x_1}f||_0^2+||1||_0^2||\partial_{x_2}f||_0^2$$
By applying Cauchy-Schwarz it follows,

$$||1||_0^2||\partial_{x_1}f||_0^2+||1||_0^2||\partial_{x_2}f||_0^2\geq\langle1,\partial_{x_1}f\rangle_0^2+\langle1,\partial_{x_2}f\rangle_0^2=(\int_D\partial_{x_1}fdx)^2+(\int_D\partial_{x_2}fdx)^2$$

Now I know I could use the following identity to get $||f||_0^2$ somewhen.

$$f(x_1,x_2)=\int_{-d}^{x_1}\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)ds$$

But everytime I am applying the equality I am ending up having too many integrals in the end...

Could someone help me? Thanks!